# Can i do conditional or selective SELECT statement on SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Is there a a way to select a `SELECT` statement?

I meant that, in a single query, for a table named vendors with `salary` and `bonus` and `vendor type`. I wanted to display, in a single query, the vendor salary if vendor type is 'fruit vendor' and bonus only if the vendor is 'tire vendor' ?

Is there a way to do that? thank you.

Comment: Please do state a reason when down voting this so I can be aware of my faults. Thank  you.

Comment: Can you put some sample data, and required output with your question? As per the current question it seems @ajmalmhd04 has answered your question.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not giving enough info. Forgot to put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't simple as this:?

```
SELECT salary + CASE WHEN vendor_type = 'tire vendor' 
                     THEN bonus ELSE 0 
                     END vendor_salary
FROM vendors;
```

/

or, if you need salary in the case of fruit vendor , and bonus if tire vendor, then you can query as:

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN vendor_type = 'fruit vendor' 
          THEN salary 
          WHEN vendor_type= 'tire vendor' 
          THEN bonus 
     END vendor_salary
FROM vendors;
```

Hope you just need a `CASE` clause.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, apparently I did not know the existence of a CASE statement. Glad to know. I should also be looking for more available functions for sql.